# submit form using mootools

Tags: mootools

I have made a class that handles load and submit of a html form. See code below

```
ND.Form = new Class({
    //--- Implements options og events.
    Implements: [Options, Events],

    //--- Options.
    options: {
        url: '',
        injectTo: ''
    },

    //--- Initialize the class.
    initialize: function (panel, options) {
        //--- Set options
        this.setOptions(options);
        this.panel = panel;
        this.loadForm();
    },

    loadForm: function () {
        var req = new Request.HTML({
            url: this.options.url,
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function (html) {
                $(this.options.injectTo).empty();
                $(this.options.injectTo).adopt(html);
                var formId = $(this.options.injectTo).getFirst('form').get('id');
                $(formId).addEvent('submit', function (e) {
                    e.stop();
                    this.submitForm(formId);
                } .bind(this));
            } .bind(this)
        }).send();
    },

    submitForm: function (formId) {
        $(formId).set('send', {
            onSuccess: function (resp) {
                this.panel.loadContent();
                if (resp != null) {
                    $('lbl_error').empty();
                    $('lbl_error').setStyles({ 'display': 'block', 'color': 'red' }).set('html', resp);
                }
            }.bind(this),

            onFailure: function (resp) {
                if (resp != null) {
                    $('lbl_error').empty();
                    $('lbl_error').setStyles({ 'display': 'block', 'color': 'red' }).set('html', resp);
                }
            }
        });
        $(formId).send();
    }
});
```

And it all works just fine, exept that when i push the save button more than ones the "this.panel.loadContent();" in the "submitForm: function (formId)" fires the same x amount of times I have pushed the button, how can i prevent this ?

/Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from mootools 1.3 "set('send')" adds another one event.
So You need to write:

```
$('myForm').set('send', {
    onSuccess: function (html) {},
    onFailure: function(xhr){}
}).addEvent('submit', function(e){
    e.stop();
    this.send();
});
```

instead of:

```
$('myForm').addEvent('submit', function(e){
    e.stop();
    this.set('send', {
        onSuccess: function (html) {},
        onFailure: function(xhr){}
    });
}).send();
```

Then Request will be sent only once each time when You handle form.

Answer (score 4):

```
Basically we need to do three things:
```

1. Listen for the ‘click’ event on the submit button.
2. Stop the event from submitting the form.
3. Send the form using $(formElement).send()

A solution could look something like this:

```
$('submit').addEvent( 'click', function(evt){
     // Stops the submission of the form.
     new Event(evt).stop();

     // Sends the form to the action path,
     // which is 'script.php'
     $('myForm').send();
    } );
```

Comment: Well, my "this.panel.loadContent();" still fires multiple times when i try your suggestion. First time I hit the button it loads once, second time I hit the button it loads twice ect.

Comment: What if the form is submitted without clicking submit? I.e. if the user presses enter inside a text input?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the request.send() method but googled trying to find a way to just replicate the action of a user hitting a form submit button, but with also allowing some javascript logic being performed beforehand. I did not find anything in discussions specifically addressing this. The answer I found is to use the form.submit() method.